# Unable to create a constant value of type . Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following method for a generic check exist,

```
public virtual bool CheckExist(T entity)
{
    var context = new eTRdataEntities();
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
    if (dbQuery.Any(e => e == entity))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

However it returns the exception:

Unable to create a constant value of type . Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Please advice,

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the code by taking in the type T next to the method name, like this:

```
public virtual bool CheckExist<T>(T entity)
{
    var context = new eTRIKSdataEntities();
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
    if (dbQuery.Any(e => e == entity))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You may also want to restrict the type to classes only, like this:

```
public virtual bool CheckExist<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    var context = new eTRIKSdataEntities();
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
    if (dbQuery.Any(e => e == entity))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the change :)  I will edit my post

Comment: You could change your if statement to `return dbQuery.Any(e => e == entity);`